# angular 4 maintain different copy of common filters for each page

Tags: javascript, angular, redux

my angular application consist of some common custom filters with different report pages.
User Can navigate from one page to another page and he can change filter for each page.
Need to add feature so common filters would maintain for each page.Whenuser navigated back to previous page it should display same filters that user selected in previous page.

For Above use case is it right to use ng-redux else how i can achieve this in angular 4

Please suggest best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by navigating from one page to another, you are basically routing to different routes. Therefore to have the information of your selected filter for each page, you can add that information to the routing parameter.

Something like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/your_route_name',{parameterName: parameterValue}]);
```

And on the routed component, it can be received as such:

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('parameterName')
```

Or else you can have a service running globally between your routes, which is not recommended as it populates the global space unnecessarily.

Comment: Currently I am using shared module for it right now as these common filters will show for all pages ..but now i want to maintain what user selected for each page.. i can create array of objects and maintain for each page ..but i am exploring if i could use better approach

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.Although, you are using a Shared module for the same, the modules must be exported from the shared module to be used in another module (say xyz). So the module (xyz) must be aware of the current state of that common component (in your case: the common filter), which I said can be done using a service or the route snapshots.